# Put each object result into a span3 rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i am wanting to put each result i get from my model into a span 3 using twitter bootstrap, this is what i have done so far but rather than each result alligning vertically they are stacked horizontally. is there anything that i am missing here?

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <% @recipes.each do |r| %>
   <div class="span3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
     <%= image_tag r.avatar.url(:myrecipes) %>
    </div>
    <h4><%= link_to r.dish_name, r %></h4>
    <hr>
    <p><%= r.description %></p>
    <p><%= link_to "Edit Recipe", edit_recipe_path(r.id) %></p>
    <p><%= link_to "Delete Recipe", recipe_path(r.id), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %></p>
    <p><%= link_to "Add to favorites",  {:controller => 'favourites', :action => 'create', :recipe_id => r.id}, {:method => :post } %></p>
    <% end %>
   </div><!--/span3-->
   </div><!--/row-->
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move your `</div><!-- /span3 -->` *before* the `<% end %>`.

For now, in your loop you open as many divs as you have recipes objects, but only close one outside of the loop.